# Using user's token to make requests to Twitter API in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, omniauth

I'm using Omniauth to get credentials from Twitter for a specific User.  Part of the OmniAuth object that I get is like this:

```
credentials=#
<Hashie::Mash secret="XXXX" token="XXXX">
extra=#<Hashie::Mash access_token=#<OAuth::AccessToken:xxxx @token="xxxx", @secret="xxxxx", ..
```

Right now I'm storing the `credentials[token]` and the `UID` for that specific User.  At some point I want to fetch the Twitter API using the auth for that specific User to avoid getting the 150 max requests for a specific IP.  Right now I'm just doing this:

```
twitter_user_name = Twitter.user(user_id).screen_name
```

So, how can I do to make those requests using the **Twitter gem** using the auth provided by OmniAuth instead of doing requests from my own IP (unauthenticated calls and therefore limited)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing with the gem, I've figured how to do it:

You want to create a new API object for a specific User, so you want to do this:

```
client = Twitter::Client.new(:oauth_token => 'XXXXX', :oauth_token_secret => 'XXXX')
```

And use this client to do the requests.